# Trying to append CSS to the head of a HTML page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm attempting to append CSS styling to the head of a HTML page like so...

```
var HEAD = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
s = document.createElement('Style');
s.id = 'cssp';
s.type = 'text/css';
s.innerHTML = ecks.cssp;
HEAD.appendChild(s);
```

However the CSS located in `ecks.cssp` never appears in the HTML page. What am I doing wrong?

Just an fyi, I'm using chrome to test.

Comment: what does ecks.cssp contains?

Comment: ecks is a `HTMLStyleElement`, ecks.cssp is the `CSS` itself.

Comment: OK... naveen is right... what is ecks? And what does it contain? However you can insert a src="file.css" in the tag so that you'll create a stylesheet linked to an external file.

Comment: You have tried to print ecks.cssp? Does javascript have access to the content? for examples just trying to do alert(ecks.cssp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are ways to add a style element, but they are browser dependent, unlike adding a link.

The string must be valid css.

```
function addStyle(str){
    var el= document.createElement('STYLE');
    el.type= 'text/css';
    el.media= 'screen';
    if(el.styleSheet){
        // IE
        el.styleSheet.cssText= str;
    }
    else{
        // Most browsers
        el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(str));
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0].appendChild(el);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip founded on Google and adapted to you:

```
function loadcss(filename){
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadcss("mystyle.css", "css") //dynamically load and add this .css file
```

The link also contains the source to load JS.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

Comment: Don't use `setAttribute` to set those properties, just use DOM element's properties directly, or in some cases you'll make IE cry.

Comment: I wasn't checking navigator compatibility, but thanks for the tip! :)