# HTML characters converted on el.appendChild(document.createTextNode())

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have a dynamic CSS loader such as:

```
function(css,onlyIE){
    var el = document.createElement('style');
    el.type = 'text/css';
    el.media= 'screen';
    if((typeof onlyIE != "undefined" && onlyIE && el.styleSheet) || typeof onlyIE == "undefined" || !onlyIE){
    // Mode IE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758524/trying-to-append-css-to-the-head-of-a-html-page-using-javascript
        if (el.styleSheet){
            el.styleSheet.cssText= css;
        }else{ // Mode standard
            el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(el);
    }
}
```

The problem starts when I have a CSS which contains `>` it gets translated to `& gt;`.

For example:

```
body > div{
   color: red;
}
```

Do you have any solution to avoid this problem?

The browser I'm using is FF 12.

Comment: It seems to me that this is IE only problem – have you checked in other browsers?

Comment: Did you debug to check if `css` don't reach the function like that? In other words, how do you call this function?

Comment: the browser is FF and it adds the style to the head, with badly encoded CSS, the css before adding is correctly encoded